# how to develop multiple pages registration form

Tags: 7

I want to develop a registration form employees based on different steps like company,salary,interview,pors and crons etc. they are pages for the registration process.
Can anyone tell me how to develop this kind of functionality?

Answer (score 1):

Try the [Multi-Step Registration](https://www.drupal.org/project/step) module

> With Multi-Step Registration you can create multi-step (wizard) user account registration forms. Each step of the wizard can be configured to, optionally, expose one ore more [Profile2](https://drupal.org/project/profile2) types.

You can also achieve that by creating a custom module. Checkout this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7814517/3249111) and

[Altering User Registration Form to Multi-Step Drupal 7](https://www.drupal.org/node/999420)